# How to store data as a database in cocos2dx (c++) ios game

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am totally new to cocos2d-x ios game development and really learning a lot from stackoverflow.Just want to thank all the software coders.Now my question is I am making a game with levels and high score.But still couldn't find a way to store the high score and the levels cleared.When the game restarts all the values are set to initial values as there is no database to fetch.I have heard about userdefault in cocos2d-x but really couldn't find a way to execute. Can anyone help me with a sample. I will be thankful to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CCUserDefault acts as a key value pair and stores a value corresponding to the keys.Suppose you want to store a high score of your game so that when the user restarts the game after exiting,the changes should persist
For this,in your .cpp file take a const key value at the top after header inclusion

```
const char *HIGH_SCORE="key1";
```

key1 is a key and this key must be different for every const char * which you declare
Delete the lines in init function after these lines upto return true statement.

```
if(!CCLayer::init())
{
return false;
}
```

Don’t delete return true.Then in your init function write the following code

```
CCUserDefault *def=CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault();
def->setIntegerForKey(HIGH_SCORE, 2000);
def->flush();
```

Here def is a pointer to CCUserDefault and it will help to access all the methods in that class.
SetIntegerForKey is the method which sets the corresponding integer value to the constant char *.
There are many more functions to store string, float, bool and double values.

def->flush() is a function which flushes the contents to the xml file. It basically saves the data to the xml file

To retrieve values from the key,suppose we want to retrieve the high score and display on a label

```
int high_score=def->getIntegerForKey(HIGH_SCORE);
```

Here we are converting the integer into a string so that we can display on a label

```
char s[4];
sprintf(s,"%d", high);
```

Adding the score to a label

```
CCLabelTTF *high_label=CCLabelTTF::create(s, "Arial.fnt", 20);
high_label->setPosition(ccp(200,200));
this->addChild(high_label);
```

Now run your project and you will see 2000 on the screen

Now stop the run and comment the following lines

```
//def->setIntegerForKey(HIGH_SCORE, 2000);
//def->flush();
```

Again re run the project and still the value is 2000 on the screen.It means that now HIGH_SCORE is stored in the xml file and the value is retrieved from it.Therefore the changes persist even after application is closed

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store basic information like High Score, Current Level etc then you can use `CCUserDefault` and if you want to store complex data then either you can use `SQLite` or `CCDictionary`

Here is pseudo code to store and retrieve High Score in `Cocos2dx-3.0`:

```
const char* KEY_HIGH_SCORE = "high_score";

// Store High Score
UserDefault::getInstance()->setIntegerForKey(KEY_HIGH_SCORE, 100);

// Retrieve High Score.
int high_score = UserDefault::getInstance()->getIntegerForKey(KEY_HIGH_SCORE);
```